# Open-source notes to Basic Algebra by Jacobson

Tags: abstract-algebra, self-learning

I am currently self-studying mathematics.

I have background readings of Stephen Abbott - Understanding analysis, a fair understanding on set-theory through online read-abouts, and E.A. Maxwell Advanced Algebra I & II. Along with a first semester course in Calculus.

I want to proceed with abstract Algebra, because I enjoy abstract thinking, and understanding how abstract thinking is possible, along with, formulating truths.

Having begun with Basic Algebra I by Jacobson, as it's most recommended by many on the web. I know i will find the content fairly difficult to grasp, but with time and maturity, I will understand the ideas. However, I wish to have supplementary notes (if available) to complement my reading and practice of the book.

Hence, I ask if anyone has open-sourced notes on this particular book?

Comment: I am surprised you find Jacobson "most recommended".  For a first pass through the subject I think other books are a better idea, such as Dummit & Foote's Abstract Algebra or Beachy & Blair's Abstract Algebra.

Comment: @KCD Thank you for the suggestions. Do you know of any open-source notes that accompany the texts you have mentioned? That would be tremendously helpful, and I'll be willing to give them a tackle if the resources are more openly available for them.

Comment: You write about wanting to read a textbook and open-source notes for the book.  Why the emphasis on "open source notes"? If you want a book then read the book itself. If you want free lecture notes on topics in math then you can easily find those online instead and you don't need an official textbook.

Comment: Whilst I wish to refrain from debating or arguing with you, could you be more helpful in providing me an actual answer (i.e. links to resources) to my questions? Whilst it may not be necessary, open-sourced notes are sufficient for my development alongside the book. Apologies, I most likely learn things in a way different to you.

Comment: I don't know of notes *specifically* written to accompany a textbook, but there are tons of online lecture notes on abstract algebra.  If you read a section of a textbook and want to find online notes related to it, just search on keywords from that section. For example, if a section of the book is on symmetric groups then look up "symmetric group notes".  What were the open-source notes you read to accompany Abbott's book?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your question, I doubt there are notes specifically written for Jacobson's book.

If you want lecture notes to serve as parallel reading for parts of Jacobson, I might suggest the ones James Milne has published on [his website](https://www.jmilne.org/), particularly on group theory, commutative algebra and field theory. There's more material in them about effective computations (including by computer).

If you want a book on algebra that has accompanying notes, George Bergman wrote *A Companion to Lang's Algebra*. It's available [here.](https://math.berkeley.edu/%7Egbergman/.C.to.L/)

Contrary to some of the comments, I don't think it's crazy to attempt Jacobson, especially given you've read the second volume of Maxwell. That being said, you need to be aware that Jacobson is at a higher level of difficulty than most books that cover similar material. Also, Jacobson probably implicitly assumes that the reader has seen more linear algebra than your background would indicate, so overall you may find that the problems are hard for you whenever there is some linear algebra involved. You may know most of the facts you need but not have used them in hard enough problems. I don't want to make it sound like this is an absolute prerequisite, but you can get up to speed quickly by reading a book like Halmos's concise *Finite-Dimensional Vector Spaces*.

If you find you need to take a step down in difficulty from Jacobson, a good book that also treats linear algebra from scratch and is still at a higher level than most undergraduate books is *Algebra* by Godement. (I would recommend skipping the chapter on logic, however.) On the whole, I'd say the problems in Godement are harder than in Artin or Dummit and Foote, but the subject isn't taken as far. Jacobson would make a good follow-on from Godement.